# Question on average.

Tags: arithmetic, average

[image]

a)Monaco b)France c)Switzerland d)Italy

What I know:

$$\text{Average} = \frac{\text{sum of observations}}{\text{total no of observations}}$$

Comment: What you know is all you need to know, along with the numbers given in the text. The next step is to apply that formula to different populations (just France, all of Europe, and all of Europe without France spring to mind, but do the other countries too) and see what you can conclude.

Comment: Please include at least an attempt to the solution

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
184 & = \text{average} = \frac{\text{sum of observations}}{\text{number of observations}} \\[12pt]
& = \frac{\text{sum of observations from France}+\text{sum of observations from Italy} + \cdots}{\text{number of obervations}} \\[12pt]
& = \frac{(\text{population of France}\times 183) + (\text{population of Italy} \times186) + \cdots}{\text{number of obervations}}
\end{align}
and so on.

Can you work with that and then see if you have further questions?